# Is an explicit NUL-byte necessary at the end of a bytearray for cython to be able to convert it to a null-terminated C-string

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cpython, python-internals

When converting a `bytearray`-object (or a `bytes`-object for that matter) to a C-string, the [cython-documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#passing-byte-strings) recommends to use the following:

```
cdef char * cstr = py_bytearray
```

there is no overhead, as `cstr` is pointing to the buffer of the `bytearray`-object.

However, C-strings are [null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and thus in order to be able to pass `cstr` to a C-function it must also be null-terminated. The cython-documentation doesn't provide any information, whether the resulting C-strings are null-terminated.

It is possible to add a `NUL`-byte explicitly to the `byarray`-object, e.g. by using `b'text\x00'` instead of just `b'text'. Yet this is cumbersome, easy to forget, and there is at least experimental evidence, that the explicit NUL-byte is not needed:

```
%%cython
from libc.stdio cimport printf
def printit(py_bytearray):
    cdef char *ptr = py_bytearray
    printf("%s\n", ptr)
```

And now

```
printit(bytearray(b'text'))
```

prints the desired "text" to stdout (which, in the case an IPython-notebook, is obviously not the output shown in the browser).

But is this a lucky coincidence or is there a guarantee, that the buffer of a bytearray-object (or a bytes-object) is null-terminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's safe (at least in Python 3), however I'd be a bit wary.

Cython uses the C-API function `PyByteArray_AsString`. The [Python3 documentation for it](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytearray.html#c.PyByteArray_AsString) says "The returned array always has an extra null byte appended." The [Python2 version](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bytearray.html#c.PyByteArray_AsString) does not have that note so it's difficult to be sure if it's safe.

Practically speaking, I think Python deals with this by always over-allocating bytearrays by one and NULL terminating them (see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L263) for one example of where this is done).

The only reason to be a bit cautious is that it's perfectly acceptable for bytearrays (and Python strings for that matter) to contain a 0 byte within the string, so it isn't a good indicator of where the end is. Therefore, you should really be using their `len` anyway. (This is a weak argument though, especially since you're probably the one initializing them, so you know if this should be true)

---

(My initial version of this answer had something about `_PyByteArray_empty_string`. @ead pointed out in the comments that I was mistaken about this and hence it's edited out...)

Comment: Thanks for this great investigation. This a whole bunch of information - will need some time to digest it. To me it looks as if `_PyByteArray_empty_string` is null-terminated: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L17. So it seems to be safe for Python3.

Comment: Your second point is very valid. However, the problem in this case in the C-API which expects a null-terminated string  and sometimes cannot be changed.

Comment: Good spot with `_PyByteArray_empty_string`, I'd only seen the declaration (not the definition) and had jumped to the wrong conclusion. It should be fine.

Comment: To me it looks like as if  Python2 also appends a trailing zero (e.g. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L288). Probably it is a bug in the documentation - in the Python3 it was fixed some time ago (https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0a560a11af0ccc816d1172180f44e5afb34ba600) , but was not ported to 2.7. I submitted a bug report (https://bugs.python.org/issue33740) in the hope the guys would confirm my assumption - but no reaction so far.